# Immutable Map implementation for huge maps

Tags: scala, dictionary, immutability, out-of-memory, scala-2.7

If I have an **immutable** Map which I might expect (over a very short period of time - like a few seconds) to be adding/removing *hundreds of thousands* of items from, is the standard `HashMap` a bad idea? Let's say I want to pass 1Gb of data through the Map in <10 seconds in such a way that the maximum size of the Map at any once instant is only 256Mb.

I get the impression that the map keeps some kind of "history" but I will *always* be accessing the last-updated table (i.e. I do not pass the map around) because it is a private member variable of an `Actor` which is updated/accessed only from within reactions.

Basically I suspect that this data structure may be (partly) at fault [for issues I am seeing around JVMs going out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297920/jvm-outofmemory-error-death-spiral-not-memory-leak) when reading in large amounts of data in a short time.

Would I be better off with a different map implementation and, if so, what is it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ouch.  Why do you have to use an immutable map?  Poor garbage collector!  Immutable maps generally require (log n) new objects per operation in addition to (log n) time, or they really just wrap mutable hash maps and layer changesets on top (which slows things down and can increase the number of object creations).

Immutability is great, but this does not seem to me like the time to use it.  If I were you, I'd stick with `scala.collection.mutable.HashMap`.  If you need concurrent access, wrap the Java util.concurrent one instead.

You also might want to increase the size of the young generation in the JVM: `-Xmn1G` or more (assuming you're running with `-Xmx3G`).  Also, use the throughput (parallel) garbage collector.

Comment: Yes - I've changed it to use the mutable Map but I though the whole point of FP was that immutability was great! This app should easily run in less than 256Mb of memory from a "how much data does it really need at any one point in time" perspective.

Comment: How great immutability is depends on the application.  If you are running an application with, say, trees of message threads being sent around to a bunch of clients, immutability is a godsend--you just send the current tree and you don't have to worry about the data structure itself changing out from under you.  (You do still have to catch cases like the client asking to add a comment to a thread that is deleted by the time they respond.)  For high-throughput work in private data structures that are turning over very rapidly, immutability provides few advantages and demands a lot of overhead.

Comment: yeah, that'swhat I'm finding out! So how do Haskell or Clojure manage in these situations? Don't they *enforce* immutability?

Comment: In FP one would prefer a map based on an ordered, balanced tree, rather than one based on a hashtable - exactly because it's hard to get a persistent version of that. From my understanding, FP people are quick to give up a hashtable's O(1) lookup for a balanced tree's O(logn), with a reasoning basically amounting to "who cares about *that* much performance, it doesn't matter, I like immutability more". Well, some people just prefer performance :)

Comment: AFAICT, Clojure uses Java's collections when it needs mutable data structures.  Haskell uses the best available immutable algorithms and then considers an occasional log N as a worthwhile sacrifice for purity.

Comment: Haskell has escape hatches for when you can't get the performance you need from immutable data structures.  For example, Haskell's Data.HashTable operations are in the IO monad (which essentially means that they're not purely functional).

Answer (score 8):

That would be awful. You say you always want to access the last-updated table, that means you only need an *ephemeral* data structure, there is no need to pay the cost for a *persistent* data structure - it's like trading time and memory to gain completely arguable "style points". You are *not* building your karma by using blindly persistent structures when they are not called for.

Also, a hashtable is a particularly difficult structure to make persistent. In other words, "very, very slow" (basically it is usable when reads greatly outnumber writes - and you seem to talk about many writes).

By the way, a `ConcurrentHashMap` wouldn't make sense in this design, given that the map is accessed from a single actor (that's what I understand from the description).

Comment: You're right - I have no requirement for immutability or concurrency. My map is a cache private to a single actor

Comment: I assume, since you are using actors, you want to take advantage of concurrency opportunities. This map/actor, which now sounds like a potential bottleneck, might be a good such opportunity (irrelevant from actors though), i.e. you might benefit by making the map a shared ConcurrentHashMap (not owned by any single actor) and let writers proceed concurrently, if possible/reasonable.

Comment: The data is the map does not need to be shared between actors - there are about 30 actor-instances, each with their own maps (of data relevant only to them)

Comment: Too often I hear the solution to immutable map performance issues in Scala is "go mutable"... You can't talk about "style points" when it comes to sticking to immutable data structures in functional programming, it's much more fundamental and important than that. Either we can do it and there is really a different programming paradigm, or we have to second-guess ourselves _every time_, and therefore there is no real viable new programming paradigm here.

Answer (score 4):

Scala's so-called(*) immutable Map is broken beyond basic usage up to Scala 2.7. Don't trust me, just look up the number of open tickets for it. And the solution is just "it will be replaced with something else on Scala 2.8" (which it did).

So, if you want an immutable map for Scala 2.7.x, I'd advise looking for it in something other than Scala. Or just use TreeHashMap instead.

(*) Scala's immutable Map isn't really immutable. It is a mutable data structure internally, which requires lot of synchronization.

Comment: Where do I find an alternative? Is `TreeMap` OK? I can hardly find one in Java

Comment: @oxbow I think people were using `HashTreeMap` as an alternative indeed, now that you mention it.

Comment: Scala's immutable map seems to have been fixed recently.  The code is a trie now, the old logging scheme seems to be gone.