# Java crashed application - how to find out why Java crashed?

Tags: java, crash, jvm, out-of-memory, jvm-crash

My java server started to crash repeatedly, and I can't find why.

I have server with 7.5GB memory and I have allocated 3GB for the java process.

Server was running fine, and ran garbage collection many times, but the JVM crashed when under memory pressure.

Here is the info from JConsole, after the crash:

```
Current heap size: 
2 958 868 kbytes
Maximum heap size: 
3 066 816 kbytes
Committed memory: 
3 066 816 kbytes
Pending finalization: 
0 objects
Garbage collector: 
Name = 'PS MarkSweep', Collections = 66, Total time spent = 7 minutes
Garbage collector: 
Name = 'PS Scavenge', Collections = 43 055, Total time spent = 44 minutes



Operating System: 
Linux 2.6.31-302-ec2
Architecture: 
amd64
Number of processors: 
2
Committed virtual memory: 
8 405 760 kbytes
Total physical memory: 
7 882 780 kbytes
Free physical memory: 
   34 540 kbytes
Total swap space: 
        0 kbytes
Free swap space: 
        0 kbytes
```

I have 0.5 GB after a GC run, so all the time it raises from 0.5 to 3 GB and than fall back to 0.5, it is absolutely not problem with hanging objects. In fact it should throw `OutOfMemoryException` instead of crashing. I am using those parameters:

```
-Xmn256m -Xms768m -Xmx3000m -XX:NewRatio=2 -server -verbosegc -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -XX:+UseParallelOldGC
```

What is wrong and what shall I do? The output shown was:

```
Current thread (0x00007fe899755800):  JavaThread "508616253@qtp-1871151428-3352" [_thread_in_vm, id=11941, stack(0x00007fe86a4e5000,0x00007fe86a5e6000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=128 (), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x00007fe9c60333b8, RBX=0x00007fe899755800, RCX=0x0d00007fe8f58787, RDX=0x00007fe9c6031888
RSP=0x00007fe86a5e3fd0, RBP=0x00007fe86a5e4020, RSI=0x00007fe899755800, RDI=0x00007fe95bae1770
R8 =0x00007fe9be341620, R9 =0x0000000000000001, R10=0x00007fe9c5b84460, R11=0x00007fe9c051a52b
R12=0x00007fe9c051a529, R13=0x00007fe9c6034ac0, R14=0x00007fe9c051a599, R15=0x0900007fe8f58787
RIP=0x00007fe9c5bd562d, EFL=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x000000000000e033, ERR=0x0000000000000000
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000d

Stack: [0x00007fe86a4e5000,0x00007fe86a5e6000],  sp=0x00007fe86a5e3fd0,  free space=3fb0000000000000030k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x64d62d]
V  [libjvm.so+0x5fc4df]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
v  ~RuntimeStub::_complete_monitor_locking_Java
J  sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
J  org.mortbay.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint.flush(Lorg/mortbay/io/Buffer;)I
J  org.mortbay.jetty.HttpGenerator.flush()J
...
```

Comment: Are there any JNI components?

Comment: the very fact that you're 'doing' GC many times should set of alarm bells. what's the server's behaviour if you do not do any GC and rely on the JVM to perform it as it sees best?

Comment: What programs are running? Java performs garbage collection by itself, but if a program incurs a memory leak this may not be enough.

Comment: No there is no JNI used.

Comment: Server is on heavy load, houndrets of connected users online, those often garbage collection calls are fast garbage collection algorithms configured by myself, which help to prevent time leaks while doing regular GB colection.

Comment: Have you load balanced your server?  What's the elapsed time between crashes?

Answer (score 1):

From the crash doc you linked, the error is a SIGSEGV which is a fault reading/writing to native memory. The thread stack shows it crashed in JVM code.

```
Current thread (0x00007fe899755800):  JavaThread "508616253@qtp-1871151428-3352" [_thread_in_vm, id=11941, stack(0x00007fe86a4e5000,0x00007fe86a5e6000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=128 (), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x00007fe9c60333b8, RBX=0x00007fe899755800, RCX=0x0d00007fe8f58787, RDX=0x00007fe9c6031888
RSP=0x00007fe86a5e3fd0, RBP=0x00007fe86a5e4020, RSI=0x00007fe899755800, RDI=0x00007fe95bae1770
R8 =0x00007fe9be341620, R9 =0x0000000000000001, R10=0x00007fe9c5b84460, R11=0x00007fe9c051a52b
R12=0x00007fe9c051a529, R13=0x00007fe9c6034ac0, R14=0x00007fe9c051a599, R15=0x0900007fe8f58787
RIP=0x00007fe9c5bd562d, EFL=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x000000000000e033, ERR=0x0000000000000000
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000d

Stack: [0x00007fe86a4e5000,0x00007fe86a5e6000],  sp=0x00007fe86a5e3fd0,  free space=3fb0000000000000030k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x64d62d]
V  [libjvm.so+0x5fc4df]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
v  ~RuntimeStub::_complete_monitor_locking_Java
J  sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
J  org.mortbay.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint.flush(Lorg/mortbay/io/Buffer;)I
J  org.mortbay.jetty.HttpGenerator.flush()J
<snip>
```

Could be a JVM bug, or perhaps memory corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a memory leak. The gc can only clean up objects that aren't referenced anymore. And, if your application (or the server itself) doesn't "free" unused ressources, after a while, even 3GB are not enough.

A Profiler might help to identify datastructures that grow unexpectedly.

---

Idea: start the server with `-verbose:gc` option and check what happens just before it dies. Decrease heap space for the test so that you don't have to wait to long. If it's a memory leak I expect that you see regular full gc cycle where the gc can free less memory each time it runs.

---

**Update**

I was mislead by the `outofmemoryerror` tag. In fact, it's a JVM crash and all you can do is trying to update the installed Java. There are already some reports on "SIGSEGV (0xb)" crashes for builds 1.6.0_17 and 1.6.0_18 ([like this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299250/java-vm-reproducable-sigsegv-on-both-1-6-0-17-and-1-6-0-18-how-to-report)).

It's an JVM internal problem.

Comment: And then switch to jmap and jhat to help diagnose the leak.

Comment: Nope, it is garbage to be cleaned. I have all the time 0,5 gb after GB run, so all the time it raises from 0,5 to 3 GB and than fall back to 0,5, it is absolutly not problem with hanging objects. In fact it suould throw OutOfMemoryException instead  of crash and no Exception.  I am using those params:  -Xmn256m -Xms768m -Xmx3000m -XX:NewRatio=2 -server -verbosegc -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8  -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2  -XX:+UseParallelOldGC

Comment: I will strongly recommend against tinkering with the JVM parameters until you have a reliable configuration working!  Also this information is so important that it should go in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you with "a memory problem" mean that you are worried that your physical hardware is defective, you should strongly consider stress testing it.

For traditional PC's the usual way to do this is with memtest86.  The latest version appears to be available from here: http://www.memtest.org/

If the memory pass an all-night test with memtest86 you can be pretty certain it works correctly.

Comment: I am using amazon server, fresh 1 day old machine, since old virtual machine was defective, I hoped that new fresh will help. It is absolutly not hardware problem. It can be only linux problem, if it is not java problem.

Comment: Good, then that is clarified.   Look into jvisualvm in the JDK - it allows you to profile a running application - you need to look for memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you allocated 3 GB to the JVM, was this the heap size or the total size (which can be quite a bit bigger) e.g. a JVM with a 3 GB heap could use clsoe to 4 GB in total.

If the JVM has crashed on a GC, I would check you have a current version of the JVM, like Java 6 update 23.

What was the crash? Sometimes the same crash is reported by other people and you can google for it. Sometimes there is a suggested solution.

Comment: I alocated only 3GB, and I have 4,5Gb aditional free to use, so I have 7,5GB total. It is free momemory, no other big proceses running on the linux.

Comment: And also I used to JAVA 5, JAVA 6 latest one, OpenJDK latest one, always same result.  And JVM has generated crash files, not everytime, but sometimes yes. You can find example of crash file here:  http://chessfriends-release.s3.amazonaws.com/logs/hs_err_pid10930.log?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJP5BYGKOCMCDVZHA&Expires=1301375337&Signature=t%2BGbqACiaF7qHJJmR3881dmLQeI%3D

Comment: I found Java 6 update 18 to be stable. But its still worth trying update 23 or 24 which uses a much newer JVM. (more than a year AFAIK)

Comment: I used 6.23 also, same result.

Comment: The only simple thing I can suggest is trying the 32-bit version (though this might not have enough memory) It looks like a JVM/native bug to me. The next thing you could do is try Ubuntu 10.x  :|

Comment: Can you try taking off as many GC options as possible. e.g. just `-mx3g` IMHO Sometimes certain combinations don't work well together and when I reduce them, the JVM behaves better.