# Sun JVM (JRE jre1.6.0_24) segfault NET_Read

Tags: java, sockets, jvm, segmentation-fault

Our JVM crashes with segmentation fault from time to time in
production with what feels like a race condition of some sort.

Setups to reproduce:
- JRE jre1.6.0_24 on Linux Ubuntu 9.10 and Debian 4.x 64 bit multicore AMD
- Apache tomcat 6.0.24 ... 6.0.32

Recompiling java with fastdebug reproduces the problem (this gcc -g1).
However, it doesn't yield much more useful information then what we
have here.

Recompiling java with debug does not reproduce the problem (this is
gcc -g plus possibly some -DSOMETHING code debug flags).

Any help trying to figure this out would be most appreciated.

Core file generated using the 1.6.0_24 jdk from Oracle . gdb turns up:

```
    Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
    #0  0x00002aaab7b10666 in NET_Read () from
    /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
```

Ok, so my assembly is really really really rusty. Keeping that in mind:

```
    (gdb) info frame
    Stack level 0, frame at 0x4b3e0040:
     rip = 0x2aaab7b10666 in NET_Read; saved rip 0x2aaab7b0d53b
     called by frame at 0x4b3f0090
             Arglist at 0x4b3dffc8, args:
     Locals at 0x4b3dffc8, Previous frame's sp is 0x4b3e0040
     Saved registers:
     rbx at 0x4b3e0008, rbp at 0x4b3e0010, r12 at 0x4b3e0018, r13 at
    0x4b3e0020, r14 at 0x4b3e0028, r15 at 0x4b3e0030, rip at 0x4b3e0038
```

So, gdb tells us that the argument  list is at:

```
    0x4b3dffc8
```

Looking at the data there:

```
    (gdb) x/8x 0x4b3dffc8
    0x4b3dffc8:     0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
    0x4b3dffd8:     0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
```

`

So no dice there. Again, my assembly dates back to 2nd wave ska, so I
can only think that either the stack is somewhat buggered, or the gcc
optimization flags generate code which uses registers for arguments
instead of the stack?

Onto the registers:

```
    (gdb) info registers
    rax            0xf2     242
                                                    rbx            0x4      4
    rcx            0x2b73aa8bfed3   47775782534867
    rdx            0x4      4
    rsi            0x4b3e0050       1262354512
            rdi            0xf2     242
    rbp            0x0      0x0
    rsp            0x4b3dffd0       0x4b3dffd0
    r8             0xffc    4092
    r9             0x2b73aa8c61b0   47775782560176
    r10            0x2b73aa8c9f78   47775782575992
    r11            0x2b73aa8b20d0   47775782478032
    r12            0xf2     242
    r13            0xf2     242
    r14            0x2aaabad4b9c8   46912767310280
    r15            0x4      4
    rip            0x2aaab7b10666   0x2aaab7b10666 <NET_Read+22>
    eflags         0x10202  [ IF RF ]
    cs             0x33     51
    ss             0x2b     43
    ds             0x0      0
    es             0x0      0
    fs             0x63     99
    gs             0x0      0
```

The disassembly (looks to me like it's faulting at Read+22):

```
    0x00002aaab7b10650 <NET_Read+0>:        push   %r15
            0x00002aaab7b10652 <NET_Read+2>:        mov    %rdx,%r15
    0x00002aaab7b10655 <NET_Read+5>:        push   %r14
                            0x00002aaab7b10657 <NET_Read+7>:        push   %r13
    0x00002aaab7b10659 <NET_Read+9>:        mov    %edi,%r13d
    0x00002aaab7b1065c <NET_Read+12>:       push   %r12
    0x00002aaab7b1065e <NET_Read+14>:       push   %rbp
    0x00002aaab7b1065f <NET_Read+15>:       push   %rbx
    0x00002aaab7b10660 <NET_Read+16>:       sub    $0x38,%rsp
    0x00002aaab7b10664 <NET_Read+20>:       test   %edi,%edi
    0x00002aaab7b10666 <NET_Read+22>:       mov    %rsi,0x8(%rsp)
    0x00002aaab7b1066b <NET_Read+27>:       js     0x2aaab7b1067c <NET_Read+44>
    0x00002aaab7b1066d <NET_Read+29>:       lea    1073812(%rip),%rax
     # 0x2aaab7c16908 <fdCount>
    0x00002aaab7b10674 <NET_Read+36>:       cmp    (%rax),%edi
    0x00002aaab7b10676 <NET_Read+38>:       jle    0x2aaab7b1070b <NET_Read+187>
    0x00002aaab7b1067c <NET_Read+44>:       xor    %ebp,%ebp
    0x00002aaab7b1067e <NET_Read+46>:       test   %rbp,%rbp
    0x00002aaab7b10681 <NET_Read+49>:       je     0x2aaab7b106f9 <NET_Read+169>
    0x00002aaab7b10683 <NET_Read+51>:       lea    0x10(%rsp),%r14
    0x00002aaab7b10688 <NET_Read+56>:       callq  0x2aaab7b03dd0 <pthread_self@plt>
    0x00002aaab7b1068d <NET_Read+61>:       mov    %rbp,%rdi
    0x00002aaab7b10690 <NET_Read+64>:       movl   $0x0,0x20(%rsp)
    0x00002aaab7b10698 <NET_Read+72>:       mov    %rax,0x10(%rsp)
    0x00002aaab7b1069d <NET_Read+77>:       callq  0x2aaab7b03f80
    <pthread_mutex_lock@plt>
    0x00002aaab7b106a2 <NET_Read+82>:       mov    %rbp,%rdi
    0x00002aaab7b106a5 <NET_Read+85>:       mov    0x28(%rbp),%rax
    0x00002aaab7b106a9 <NET_Read+89>:       mov    %rax,0x18(%rsp)
    0x00002aaab7b106ae <NET_Read+94>:       mov    %r14,0x28(%rbp)
    0x00002aaab7b106b2 <NET_Read+98>:       callq  0x2aaab7b043b0
    <pthread_mutex_unlock@plt>
    0x00002aaab7b106b7 <NET_Read+103>:      mov    %r13d,%edi
    0x00002aaab7b106ba <NET_Read+106>:      mov    0x8(%rsp),%rsi
    0x00002aaab7b106bf <NET_Read+111>:      xor    %ecx,%ecx
    0x00002aaab7b106c1 <NET_Read+113>:      mov    %r15,%rdx
    0x00002aaab7b106c4 <NET_Read+116>:      callq  0x2aaab7b04160 <recv@plt>
    0x00002aaab7b106c9 <NET_Read+121>:      mov    %rbp,%rdi
    0x00002aaab7b106cc <NET_Read+124>:      mov    %r14,%rsi
    0x00002aaab7b106cf <NET_Read+127>:      mov    %eax,%ebx
    0x00002aaab7b106d1 <NET_Read+129>:      mov    %rax,%r12
    0x00002aaab7b106d4 <NET_Read+132>:      callq  0x2aaab7b11000 <endOp>
    0x00002aaab7b106d9 <NET_Read+137>:      inc    %ebx
    0x00002aaab7b106db <NET_Read+139>:      jne    0x2aaab7b106e7 <NET_Read+151>
    0x00002aaab7b106dd <NET_Read+141>:      callq  0x2aaab7b04380
    <__errno_location@plt>
    0x00002aaab7b106e2 <NET_Read+146>:      cmpl   $0x4,(%rax)
    0x00002aaab7b106e5 <NET_Read+149>:      je     0x2aaab7b10688 <NET_Read+56>
    0x00002aaab7b106e7 <NET_Read+151>:      mov    %r12d,%eax
    0x00002aaab7b106ea <NET_Read+154>:      add    $0x38,%rsp
    0x00002aaab7b106ee <NET_Read+158>:      pop    %rbx
    0x00002aaab7b106ef <NET_Read+159>:      pop    %rbp
    0x00002aaab7b106f0 <NET_Read+160>:      pop    %r12
    0x00002aaab7b106f2 <NET_Read+162>:      pop    %r13
            0x00002aaab7b106f4 <NET_Read+164>:      pop    %r14
            0x00002aaab7b106f6 <NET_Read+166>:      pop    %r15
            0x00002aaab7b106f8 <NET_Read+168>:      retq
            0x00002aaab7b106f9 <NET_Read+169>:      callq  0x2aaab7b04380
    <__errno_location@plt>
    0x00002aaab7b106fe <NET_Read+174>:      movl   $0x9,(%rax)
    0x00002aaab7b10704 <NET_Read+180>:      mov    $0xffffffff,%eax
    0x00002aaab7b10709 <NET_Read+185>:      jmp    0x2aaab7b106ea <NET_Read+154>
    0x00002aaab7b1070b <NET_Read+187>:      movslq %edi,%rax
    0x00002aaab7b1070e <NET_Read+190>:      lea    (%rax,%rax,2),%rbp
    0x00002aaab7b10712 <NET_Read+194>:      lea    1073639(%rip),%rax
     # 0x2aaab7c16900 <fdTable>
    0x00002aaab7b10719 <NET_Read+201>:      shl    $0x4,%rbp
    0x00002aaab7b1071d <NET_Read+205>:      add    (%rax),%rbp
    ---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
    0x00002aaab7b10720 <NET_Read+208>:      jmpq   0x2aaab7b1067e <NET_Read+46>
    0x00002aaab7b10725 <NET_Read+213>:      data16
    0x00002aaab7b10726 <NET_Read+214>:      data16
    0x00002aaab7b10727 <NET_Read+215>:      data16
    0x00002aaab7b10728 <NET_Read+216>:      nop
    0x00002aaab7b10729 <NET_Read+217>:      data16
    0x00002aaab7b1072a <NET_Read+218>:      data16
    0x00002aaab7b1072b <NET_Read+219>:      data16
    0x00002aaab7b1072c <NET_Read+220>:      nop
    0x00002aaab7b1072d <NET_Read+221>:      data16
    0x00002aaab7b1072e <NET_Read+222>:      data16
    0x00002aaab7b1072f <NET_Read+223>:      nop
```

Looking at the source code for NETRead:

```
    jdk/src/solaris/native/java/net/linux_close.c

    *snip*
    /*
             * Macro to perform a blocking IO operation. Restarts
     * automatically if interrupted by signal (other than
             * our wakeup signal)
     */
    #define BLOCKING_IO_RETURN_INT(FD, FUNC) {      \
       int ret;                                    \
       threadEntry_t self;                         \
               fdEntry_t *fdEntry = getFdEntry(FD);        \
               if (fdEntry == NULL) {                      \
           errno = EBADF;                          \
           return -1;                              \
       }                                           \
       do {                                        \
           startOp(fdEntry, &self);                \
           ret = FUNC;                             \
           endOp(fdEntry, &self);                  \
       } while (ret == -1 && errno == EINTR);      \
       return ret;                                 \
    }

    int NET_Read(int s, void* buf, size_t len) {
       BLOCKING_IO_RETURN_INT( s, recv(s, buf, len, 0) );
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Reproducible JVM crashes are funny: here's one of mine...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299250  People will tell you that if you're distro is not officially supported you're SOL (which IMHO is a bit silly but whatever ; )

Comment: I'm curious where you got the Sun Java source to recompile with.  But yes - 1) you've definitely got the 64-bit JVM ("rax", "rcx", etc), 2) you say it's the Sun JVM, directly from Oracle, 3) you say you can reproduce the problem by compiling with "fastdebug", and it disappears with "-g" .... so 4) I can only say it's a problem with the GCC optimizer on this version of Java.  Q: have you tried a different version yet?

Comment: Your 'assembly' is indeed rusty: it's called 'assembler' ;)

Comment: "Any help trying to figure this out would be most appreciated.": what are you hoping to achieve? A SEGV in the JVM suggests a bug in the JVM or some JNI code. Does the program have any JNI you have written yourself? If not, all you can do is submit a bug report to Oracle. And they should thank you, because you've already gone above-and-beyond a typical bug report.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue on our production servers. The problem is basically a  stack overflow in the JNI code that is hidden as a segfault: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7059899

Try jstack to extract a thread dump from the core file produced by the VM and look for infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

is getFdEntry a macro, or inlined?  I would look in there.  Based on the assembler code dump, the seg fault happens before the first branch, just after the initial stack manipulation, and this makes it appear to be somewhere in getFdEntry.  Also, given that the call to the read is wrapped in something that looks suspiciously like a lock/unlock operation, I think your suspicion of a race condition is probably good.  Without seeing the rest of the source code it's hard to say, but my best guess is getFdEntry is an inlined function that is not as thread safe as it should be