# JVM is crashing under load after moved to java 1.6.0_25 from java 1.5

Tags: java, java-6

I have an enterprise application running on JBoss 4.2.2.GA, I am experiencing JVM crash under load. We see this behaviour when we moved to java 1.6.0_25, the same application worked fine with JDK 1.5

we observer `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen` space in load the following is the JVM crash report.

crash report is here, I removed some of the lines that references to my application

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb7474cba, pid=12085, tid=1673612176
#
# JRE version: 6.0_25-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x2f0cba]  constantPoolOopDesc::klass_at_impl(constantPoolHandle, int, Thread*)+0x1a
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x66d2e800):  JavaThread "pool-1-thread-5" [_thread_in_vm, id=12381, stack(0x63bc4000,0x63c15000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x00000004

Registers:
EAX=0x705098f0, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0xfffffffb, EDX=0x68e8ad70
ESP=0x63c138b8, EBP=0x63c13a6c, ESI=0x00000000, EDI=0x68e8ad70
EIP=0xb7474cba, EFLAGS=0x00210216, CR2=0x00000004

Top of Stack: (sp=0x63c138b8)
0x63c138b8:   63c138d8 b7832813 00000000 00000000
0x63c138c8:   63c138d8 70509c40 70509a70 b7985bc8
0x63c138d8:   63c13908 b75566ba 70509a70 68e8b540
0x63c138e8:   68e8b548 b7556626 73fa7140 63c13904
0x63c138f8:   7050a428 b7985bc8 68e8ad9c ffffffff
0x63c13908:   63c13928 b78487ac 68e8ad9c 68e8b548
0x63c13918:   68e8ad78 70509c40 b7985bc8 68e8ad9c
0x63c13928:   63c13958 b7438df0 70509a70 00000004 

Instructions: (pc=0xb7474cba)
0xb7474c9a:   5a 5b 5e 5f 5d c3 55 89 e5 57 56 53 81 ec a8 01
0xb7474caa:   00 00 8b 7d 08 8b 75 0c 8b 07 83 c0 28 8b 1c b0
0xb7474cba:   8b 43 04 8d 48 08 8b 40 08 51 ff 90 88 00 00 00
0xb7474cca:   83 c4 10 89 da 84 c0 74 0d 8d 65 f4 89 d0 5b 5e 

Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x705098f0 is an oop
{constant pool} 
 - klass: {other class}
 - cache: 0x73f9fda8
 -   1 :  : "initCause" {0x73b39b98}
 -   2 :  : '()V'
 -   3 :  : '(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;'
 -   4 :  : '(Ljava/lang/String;)V'
 -   5 :  : '(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;'
 -   6 :  : '<init>'
 -   7 :  : 'Code'
 -   8 :  : 'ConstantValue'
 -   9 :  : 'J'
 -  10 :  : 'LineNumberTable'
 -  11 :  : 'SourceFile'
 -  12 :  : 'getMethod'
 -  13 :  : 'initCause'
 -  14 :  : 'invoke'
 -  15 :  : 'java/lang/Class'
 -  16 :  : 'java/lang/Exception'
 -  17 :  : 'java/lang/Object'
 -  18 :  : 'java/lang/RuntimeException'
 -  19 :  : 'java/lang/Throwable'
 -  20 :  : 'java/lang/reflect/Method'
 -  21 :  : 'javax/management/JMRuntimeException'
 -  22 :  : 'serialVersionUID'
 -  23 :  : 6573344628407841861
 -  25 :  : 'java/lang/Class'
 -  26 :  : 'java/lang/Exception'
 -  27 :  : 'java/lang/Object'
 -  28 :  : 'java/lang/RuntimeException'
 -  29 :  : 'java/lang/Throwable'
 -  30 :  : 'java/lang/reflect/Method'
 -  31 :  : 'javax/management/JMRuntimeException'
 -  32 :  : '(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V'
 -  33 :  : name_index=6 signature_index=2
 -  34 :  : name_index=6 signature_index=4
 -  35 :  : name_index=14 signature_index=3
 -  36 :  : name_index=12 signature_index=5
 -  37 :  : klass_index=25 name_and_type_index=36
 -  38 :  : klass_index=28 name_and_type_index=33
 -  39 :  : klass_index=28 name_and_type_index=34
 -  40 :  : klass_index=30 name_and_type_index=35
 -  41 :  : 'JMRuntimeException.java'

EBX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ECX=0xfffffffb is an unknown value
EDX=0x68e8ad70 is an unknown value
ESP=0x63c138b8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x66d2e800
EBP=0x63c13a6c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x66d2e800
ESI=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDI=0x68e8ad70 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x63bc4000,0x63c15000],  sp=0x63c138b8,  free space=318k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x2f0cba]  constantPoolOopDesc::klass_at_impl(constantPoolHandle, int, Thread*)+0x1a
V  [libjvm.so+0x2f2114]  constantPoolOopDesc::klass_ref_at(int, Thread*)+0x44
V  [libjvm.so+0x531c18]  LinkResolver::resolve_klass(KlassHandle&, constantPoolHandle, int, Thread*)+0x28
V  [libjvm.so+0x535e7a]  LinkResolver::resolve_pool(KlassHandle&, symbolHandle&, symbolHandle&, KlassHandle&, constantPoolHandle, int, Thread*)+0x2a
V  [libjvm.so+0x5360e1]  LinkResolver::resolve_invokespecial(CallInfo&, constantPoolHandle, int, Thread*)+0x51
V  [libjvm.so+0x535e1c]  LinkResolver::resolve_invoke(CallInfo&, Handle, constantPoolHandle, int, Bytecodes::Code, Thread*)+0x7c
V  [libjvm.so+0x3d8ab1]  InterpreterRuntime::resolve_invoke(JavaThread*, Bytecodes::Code)+0x211
j  javax.management.JMRuntimeException.<init>()V+1
j  javax.management.RuntimeErrorException.<init>(Ljava/lang/Error;)V+1
j  org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.rethrowAsMBeanException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V+34
j  org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;+378

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  javax.management.JMRuntimeException.<init>()V+1
j  javax.management.RuntimeErrorException.<init>(Ljava/lang/Error;)V+1
j  org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.rethrowAsMBeanException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V+34
j  org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;+378
J  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(Lorg/jboss/mx/server/Invocation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke()Ljava/lang/Object;
j  org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;+347
J  org.jboss.proxy.ClientMethodInterceptor.invoke(Lorg/jboss/invocation/Invocation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run()V
J  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0a750000 JavaThread "Thread-258" [_thread_blocked, id=25569, stack(0x61eed000,0x61f3e000)]
  0x6dfd8000 JavaThread "Thread-257" [_thread_blocked, id=25547, stack(0x65f85000,0x65fd6000)]
  0x6beb6000 JavaThread "Thread-256" [_thread_blocked, id=25546, stack(0x65e92000,0x65ee3000)]
  0x6d405400 JavaThread "Thread-254" [_thread_blocked, id=25544, stack(0x65c5b000,0x65cac000)]
  0x6d401000 JavaThread "Thread-253" [_thread_blocked, id=25538, stack(0x65ee3000,0x65f34000)]
  0x6d4f6000 JavaThread "Thread-252" [_thread_blocked, id=25537, stack(0x620d3000,0x62124000)]
  0x6d42ec00 JavaThread "Thread-251" [_thread_blocked, id=25536, stack(0x65cac000,0x65cfd000)]
  0x6f3f1800 JavaThread "Thread-248" [_thread_blocked, id=25532, stack(0x68abc000,0x68b0d000)]
  0x6f3f0400 JavaThread "Thread-247" [_thread_blocked, id=25531, stack(0x65df0000,0x65e41000)]
  0x6f3ef400 JavaThread "Thread-246" [_thread_blocked, id=25530, stack(0x660c9000,0x6611a000)]
  0x6f3ee400 JavaThread "Thread-245" [_thread_blocked, id=25529, stack(0x65cfd000,0x65d4e000)]
  0x6d406800 JavaThread "Thread-230" [_thread_blocked, id=25470, stack(0x623fd000,0x6244e000)]
  0x6d4f9400 JavaThread "Thread-182" [_thread_blocked, id=25354, stack(0x62685000,0x626d6000)]
  0x6dfd9000 JavaThread "Thread-168" [_thread_blocked, id=25331, stack(0x62124000,0x62175000)]
  0x6d431000 JavaThread "Thread-167" [_thread_blocked, id=25329, stack(0x621c6000,0x62217000)]

  0x091f2000 JavaThread "[Pool-Cleaner]:Tomcat Connection Pool[3-15202739]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18956, stack(0x63a2f000,0x63a80000)]
  0x09468000 JavaThread "[Pool-Cleaner]:Tomcat Connection Pool[2-15202739]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16354, stack(0x63a80000,0x63ad1000)]
  0x09be8400 JavaThread "pool-11-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=15470, stack(0x63ad1000,0x63b22000)]
  0x0a76a000 JavaThread "pool-7-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=14710, stack(0x63b22000,0x63b73000)]
  0x0972d400 JavaThread "pool-7-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=14458, stack(0x6a8af000,0x6a900000)]
=>0x66d2e800 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-5" [_thread_in_vm, id=12381, stack(0x63bc4000,0x63c15000)]
  0x66d2f000 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=12380, stack(0x63c15000,0x63c66000)]
  0x66d2e400 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=12379, stack(0x63c66000,0x63cb7000)]
  0x6ce3e000 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-2" [_thread_in_Java, id=12378, stack(0x63cb7000,0x63d08000)]
  0x6ce3d800 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=12377, stack(0x63d08000,0x63d59000)]
  0x666fb800 JavaThread "pool-10-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=12376, stack(0x63d59000,0x63daa000)]
  0x09ad3400 JavaThread "Thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=12294, stack(0x65658000,0x656a9000)]
  0x094ee800 JavaThread "JBossLifeThread" [_thread_blocked, id=12293, stack(0x656a9000,0x656fa000)]
  0x0bd78800 JavaThread "Thread-58" [_thread_in_vm, id=12290, stack(0x6574b000,0x6579c000)]
  0x0a683c00 JavaThread "Thread-57" [_thread_blocked, id=12289, stack(0x6579c000,0x657ed000)]
  0x0a682000 JavaThread "Thread-56" [_thread_blocked, id=12288, stack(0x657ed000,0x6583e000)]
  0x0a680800 JavaThread "Thread-55" [_thread_blocked, id=12287, stack(0x6583e000,0x6588f000)]
  0x0a463c00 JavaThread "Thread-54" [_thread_blocked, id=12286, stack(0x6588f000,0x658e0000)]
  0x0a462000 JavaThread "Thread-53" [_thread_blocked, id=12285, stack(0x658e0000,0x65931000)]
  0x0a461000 JavaThread "Thread-52" [_thread_blocked, id=12284, stack(0x65931000,0x65982000)]
  0x091f7000 JavaThread "Thread-51" [_thread_blocked, id=12283, stack(0x65982000,0x659d3000)]
  0x091f5c00 JavaThread "Thread-50" [_thread_blocked, id=12282, stack(0x659d3000,0x65a24000)]
  0x0a70d400 JavaThread "Thread-49" [_thread_blocked, id=12281, stack(0x65a24000,0x65a75000)]
  0x0ab64c00 JavaThread "Thread-48" [_thread_blocked, id=12280, stack(0x65a75000,0x65ac6000)]
  0x0bb1a000 JavaThread "pool-8-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=12278, stack(0x65ac6000,0x65b17000)]
  0x09618800 JavaThread "Thread-42" [_thread_blocked, id=12277, stack(0x65b17000,0x65b68000)]
  0x095e3c00 JavaThread "Thread-47" [_thread_blocked, id=12276, stack(0x65b68000,0x65bb9000)]
  0x095e2000 JavaThread "Thread-46" [_thread_blocked, id=12275, stack(0x65bb9000,0x65c0a000)]
  0x095fd400 JavaThread "Thread-45" [_thread_blocked, id=12274, stack(0x65c0a000,0x65c5b000)]
  0x09a4b000 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=12255, stack(0x661bc000,0x6620d000)]
  0x09af5400 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=12254, stack(0x6620d000,0x6625e000)]
  0x09af4400 JavaThread "pool-7-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=12253, stack(0x6625e000,0x662af000)]
  0x098d2c00 JavaThread "pool-7-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=12252, stack(0x662af000,0x66300000)]
  0x098d2400 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=12249, stack(0x6640d000,0x6645e000)]
  0x09124400 JavaThread "Thread-26" [_thread_blocked, id=12248, stack(0x6645e000,0x664af000)]
  0x09126800 JavaThread "Thread-25" [_thread_blocked, id=12247, stack(0x664af000,0x66500000)]
  0x0bac7400 JavaThread "pool-5-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=12246, stack(0x68a1a000,0x68a6b000)]
  0x66d31000 JavaThread "Thread-21" [_thread_blocked, id=12234, stack(0x68b5e000,0x68baf000)]
  0x6d72a400 JavaThread "[Pool-Cleaner]:Tomcat Connection Pool[1-15202739]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12222, stack(0x68baf000,0x68c00000)]
  0x691f4800 JavaThread "Thread-20" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12221, stack(0x69f0d000,0x69f5e000)]
  0x697f2800 JavaThread "Thread-19" [_thread_blocked, id=12220, stack(0x69f5e000,0x69faf000)]
  0x0965f000 JavaThread "Thread-18" [_thread_blocked, id=12219, stack(0x69faf000,0x6a000000)]
  0x09629800 JavaThread "Thread-17" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12218, stack(0x6a80d000,0x6a85e000)]
  0x09661c00 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=12216, stack(0x6a85e000,0x6a8af000)]
  0x09999c00 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12197, stack(0x6b425000,0x6b476000)]
  0x09469800 JavaThread "IdleRemover" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12196, stack(0x6b476000,0x6b4c7000)]
  0x6c205c00 JavaThread "JCA PoolFiller" [_thread_blocked, id=12195, stack(0x6b4d6000,0x6b527000)]
  0x6c10fc00 JavaThread "Timer-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12194, stack(0x6b527000,0x6b578000)]
  0x6caca400 JavaThread "HSQLDB Timer @1e8614a" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12193, stack(0x6b578000,0x6b5c9000)]
  0x6baeb800 JavaThread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" [_thread_blocked, id=12192, stack(0x6b5c9000,0x6b61a000)]
  0x6c6ff800 JavaThread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9" [_thread_blocked, id=12191, stack(0x6b61a000,0x6b66b000)]
  0x6ca90800 JavaThread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8" [_thread_blocked, id=12190, stack(0x6b66b000,0x6b6bc000)]
  0x6bafc400 JavaThread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=12189, stack(0x6b6bc000,0x6b70d000)]
  0x6cacdc00 JavaThread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=12188, stack(0x6b70d000,0x6b75e000)]
  0x6de8f800 JavaThread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=12187, stack(0x6b75e000,0x6b7af000)]
  0x6c72d400 JavaThread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=12186, stack(0x6b7af000,0x6b800000)]
  0x6caff800 JavaThread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=12185, stack(0x6bb0d000,0x6bb5e000)]
  0x6dcea000 JavaThread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=12184, stack(0x6bb5e000,0x6bbaf000)]
  0x6cb19400 JavaThread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=12183, stack(0x6bbaf000,0x6bc00000)]
  0x6dc05400 JavaThread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=12182, stack(0x6bf0d000,0x6bf5e000)]
  0x6ed72c00 JavaThread "WorkManager(2)-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12181, stack(0x6bf5e000,0x6bfaf000)]
  0x6de55c00 JavaThread "Thread-12" [_thread_in_native, id=12180, stack(0x6bfaf000,0x6c000000)]
  0x6de34000 JavaThread "Thread-11" [_thread_blocked, id=12179, stack(0x6cf0d000,0x6cf5e000)]
  0x6e732400 JavaThread "Timer-2" [_thread_blocked, id=12178, stack(0x6cf5e000,0x6cfaf000)]
  0x6cafe000 JavaThread "Thread-9" [_thread_blocked, id=12167, stack(0x6cfaf000,0x6d000000)]
  0x6ba96400 JavaThread "Thread-8" [_thread_blocked, id=12166, stack(0x6d20d000,0x6d25e000)]
  0x6caf0c00 JavaThread "Timer-1" [_thread_blocked, id=12160, stack(0x6d25e000,0x6d2af000)]
  0x6decd400 JavaThread "Thread-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12159, stack(0x6d2af000,0x6d300000)]
  0x6e3e9c00 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12158, stack(0x6d83e000,0x6d88f000)]
  0x093a7800 JavaThread "ServerSocketRefresh" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12157, stack(0x6d8d6000,0x6d927000)]
  0x6dc0f800 JavaThread "AcceptorThread#0:4448" [_thread_in_native, id=12156, stack(0x6d927000,0x6d978000)]
  0x6e10a400 JavaThread "PooledInvokerAcceptor#0-4449" [_thread_in_native, id=12155, stack(0x6d978000,0x6d9c9000)]
  0x6dc1cc00 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-4450" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=12154, stack(0x6d9c9000,0x6da1a000)]
  0x6dc1e400 JavaThread "Listener:49892" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=12153, stack(0x6da1a000,0x6da6b000)]
  0x6dc12400 JavaThread "Thread-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12151, stack(0x6da6b000,0x6dabc000)]
  0x6dc06000 JavaThread "Thread-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12150, stack(0x6dabc000,0x6db0d000)]
  0x093c7000 JavaThread "Listener:36200" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=12144, stack(0x6db0d000,0x6db5e000)]
  0x6e042800 JavaThread "JBoss System Threads(1)-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=12133, stack(0x6db5e000,0x6dbaf000)]
  0x6dc14000 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12132, stack(0x6dbaf000,0x6dc00000)]
  0x6dedcc00 JavaThread "RMI Reaper" [_thread_blocked, id=12131, stack(0x6dd0d000,0x6dd5e000)]
  0x6dede800 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-1103" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=12130, stack(0x6dd5e000,0x6ddaf000)]
  0x6decdc00 JavaThread "JBoss System Threads(1)-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=12129, stack(0x6ddaf000,0x6de00000)]
  0x6e1d7c00 JavaThread "ScannerThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12128, stack(0x6e20d000,0x6e25e000)]
  0x6e1d7400 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12127, stack(0x6e25e000,0x6e2af000)]
  0x6f3a4400 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=12086, stack(0xb710d000,0xb715e000)]
  0x6f392c00 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=12101, stack(0x6efe2000,0x6f033000)]
  0x6f390000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-12345" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=12100, stack(0x6f033000,0x6f084000)]
  0x6f387c00 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=12098, stack(0x6f084000,0x6f0d5000)]
  0x6f9ac400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12097, stack(0x6f42e000,0x6f47f000)]
  0x6f9aa000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12096, stack(0x6f47f000,0x6f500000)]
  0x6f9a8000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12095, stack(0x6f500000,0x6f581000)]
  0x6f9a6800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12094, stack(0x6f581000,0x6f5d2000)]
  0x6f997800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12093, stack(0x6f611000,0x6f662000)]
  0x6f996000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12092, stack(0x6f662000,0x6f6b3000)]

Other Threads:
  0x6f992400 VMThread [stack: 0x6f6b3000,0x6f734000] [id=12091]
  0x6f394800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x6ef61000,0x6efe2000] [id=12102]

VM state:synchronizing (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x08f745c0] Safepoint_lock - owner thread: 0x6f992400
[0x08f74628] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x6f992400
[0x08f74a38] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x0a750000
[0x08f74eb0] MethodData_lock - owner thread: 0x09b02000

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 349056K, used 10913K [0x9ea50000, 0xb3fa0000, 0xb3fa0000)
  eden space 348864K, 3% used [0x9ea50000,0x9f4f8470,0xb3f00000)
  from space 192K, 0% used [0xb3f70000,0xb3f70000,0xb3fa0000)
  to   space 320K, 0% used [0xb3f00000,0xb3f00000,0xb3f50000)
 PSOldGen        total 699072K, used 82226K [0x73fa0000, 0x9ea50000, 0x9ea50000)
  object space 699072K, 11% used [0x73fa0000,0x78fec8e8,0x9ea50000)
 PSPermGen       total 65536K, used 65536K [0x6ffa0000, 0x73fa0000, 0x73fa0000)
  object space 65536K, 100% used [0x6ffa0000,0x73fa0000,0x73fa0000)

Code Cache  [0xb406c000, 0xb524c000, 0xb706c000)
 total_blobs=3954 nmethods=3748 adapters=159 free_code_cache=34445056 largest_free_block=1903360

Dynamic libraries:
08048000-08052000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2220512    /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/java
08052000-08053000 rwxp 00009000 08:01 2220512    /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/java

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dprogram.name=run.sh -Dapplication.name=be -Xms128m -Xmx1024m 
java_command: org.jboss.Main -c be -b xxxxx
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin:/usr/local/bin/xera:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin/xera
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/../lib/i386::/usr/local/lib/xera

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x725370], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x725370], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x5dfd80], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x5dfd80], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x5dfd80], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x5dfd80], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x5e2fc0], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x5e2ba0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGINT: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x5e2ba0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x5e2ba0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:lenny/sid

uname:Linux 2.6.27-14-server #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 17:21:37 UTC 2009 i686
libc:glibc 2.8.90 NPTL 2.8.90 
rlimit: STACK 4096k, CORE infinity, NPROC 24576, NOFILE 65535, AS infinity
load average:1.18 1.00 0.69

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:      3111860 kB
MemFree:         72264 kB
Buffers:        179624 kB
Cached:        1048472 kB
SwapCached:       4584 kB
Active:        1472644 kB
Inactive:       929860 kB
HighTotal:     2228160 kB
HighFree:         4276 kB
LowTotal:       883700 kB
LowFree:         67988 kB
SwapTotal:     3453932 kB
SwapFree:      3449348 kB
Dirty:            1396 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:     1165288 kB
Mapped:          32848 kB
Slab:           603016 kB
SReclaimable:   577736 kB
SUnreclaim:      25280 kB
PageTables:       4188 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
WritebackTmp:        0 kB
CommitLimit:   5009860 kB
Committed_AS:  1849336 kB
VmallocTotal:   114680 kB
VmallocUsed:      4560 kB
VmallocChunk:   109852 kB
HugePages_Total:     0
HugePages_Free:      0
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
HugePages_Surp:      0
Hugepagesize:     2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      8192 kB
DirectMap2M:    909312 kB


CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 6, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

/proc/cpuinfo:
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5410  @ 2.33GHz
stepping    : 6
cpu MHz     : 2327.524
cache size  : 6144 KB
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts pni ssse3 sse4_1
bogomips    : 4655.04
clflush size    : 64
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5410  @ 2.33GHz
stepping    : 6
cpu MHz     : 2327.524
cache size  : 6144 KB
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts pni ssse3 sse4_1
bogomips    : 4655.65
clflush size    : 64
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5410  @ 2.33GHz
stepping    : 6
cpu MHz     : 2327.524
cache size  : 6144 KB
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts pni ssse3 sse4_1
bogomips    : 4656.03
clflush size    : 64
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5410  @ 2.33GHz
stepping    : 6
cpu MHz     : 2327.524
cache size  : 6144 KB
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts pni ssse3 sse4_1
bogomips    : 4655.61
clflush size    : 64
power management:



Memory: 4k page, physical 3111860k(72264k free), swap 3453932k(3449348k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (20.0-b11) for linux-x86 JRE (1.6.0_25-b06), built on Apr 14 2011 01:12:39 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.1-7a (J2SE release)

time: Thu Nov  3 22:36:54 2011
elapsed time: 166363 seconds
```

Comment: I would try Java 6 update 29 instead of 25. If its a JVM bug it could have been fixed.

Comment: Given your perm gen is full (or having to be cleaned up when this happens) I would try a larger PermGen.

Comment: You should also probably figure out if something is abusing permgen space (I have seen this caused by Hibernate). Also permgen errors will happen if you are hot deploying over and over again. Also check this solution to a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299250/java-vm-reproducable-sigsegv-on-both-1-6-0-17-and-1-6-0-18-how-to-report

Comment: We are not hot deploying. We have upgraded the version and worked fine for two days, later we ran into issues. Under load the jvm is crashing. We have increased MaxPermSize to 128M, we will see it can fixes the problem. I want to figure out who is the culprit. As Adam said it may be hibernate, we are using hiernate hibernate-2.1. Probably adding `-XX:+TraceClassUnloading -XX:+TraceClassLoading` help us in identifying the culprit

Comment: did you find out the problem? and what tools/procedure did you use to find out?

Answer (score 3):

PermGen space is where class definitions for user defined objects are stored by the JVM.  It is likely that the permgen allocation differs between JDK 1.5 and 1.6, and it is almost certain that the bytecode generated by the two JDKs differs, so it's not surprising that you're running into issues after migrating.

Allocate additional permgen space to the JVM on startup with the following switch:
`-XX:MaxPermSize=XXXm` where XXXm is a figure in megabytes.  Beware of making this amount too large or you will likely run into other memory-related issues.

You might also want to make use of jvisualvm to profile your application server startup.  Maybe you can turn off some unnecessary functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was increased the MaxPermSize to 128MB (default is 64MB). I profiled the application with visualvm and not found any unusual until the issue happen. When the issue happen, the allocated heap size was increased due to core dump, the used heap is  constant. I would like to know what makes the difference between JDK 1.5 and 1.6. Thanks for the explanation. I will observe my application with new setting for some time, if any findings will updated on the discussion

Answer (score 0):

(Just an idea) - XML handling has changed over time. Popular was using string internalizing String.intern(), throwing XML tags into Permanent Memory. That is not as innocent as it seems. Today often a unique mapping is used instead. Maybe you have old explicit settings. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-perfap1/index.html